# What does "strain out the tea" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am looking for the meaning of "strain out tea" in the following instructions.

> Thinly slice two inches of fresh ginger and turmeric. Boil 3-4 cups of
>   water and simmer for 30 minutes. Cover and set tea aside overnight.
>   **Strain out tea**. Reheat the mixture, add any sweetener or few drops of
>   lemon and sip.

'Strain out tea' - Are they are referring to the liquid portion or the solid portion?

Also, 'Reheat the mixture' - Are they are referring to the liquid portion or the solid portion?

Comment: You throw everything in a filter. The liquid that falls through is your drink. This you can reheat.

Comment: A _tea_ is an infusion, either of actual tea or some other plant material. You pour it through a strainer to remove the solids, then drink the liquid (you can't _sip_ solids!)

Comment: Everything everyone else has written about tea and straining is true. That said, I understand why you're asking the question. The way the instructions are written is confusing. First there's _Strain out tea._ Then there's _Reheat the mixture.....and sip._ _Reheat the tea_ would have been much clearer, even though _sip_ at the end sort of makes it clear that _mixture_ (which could be the stuff you left behind when you strained out the tea) must refer to the _tea_. It's a little clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

If a liquid is 'strained', it is poured through a sieve to hold back solid particles or fragments above a certain size determined by the design of the sieve.

> strain verb (SEPARATE)
>   [ T ] to separate liquid food from solid
>   food, especially by pouring it through a utensil with small holes in it

[Strain (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain)

A special kind of small sieve intended for use when pouring tea is called a 'tea strainer':

[image]